# Screenshot of a window using python

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to take a screenshot of the curent window using a python script on linux.

I curently have a script which takes a screenshot of the entire screen:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPixmap, QApplication
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now()
filename = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.jpg')
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QPixmap.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId()).save(filename, 'jpg')
```

But a would like to have only the selected window. I know that the problem comes from grabWindow. But I don't know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

simply replace

```
QApplication.desktop()
```

with the widget you want to take the screenshot of.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now()
filename = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.jpg')
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QWidget()
# set up the QWidget...
widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

label = QLabel()
widget.layout().addWidget(label)

def shoot():
    p = QPixmap.grabWindow(widget.winId())
    p.save(filename, 'jpg')
    label.setPixmap(p)        # just for fun :)
    print "shot taken"

widget.layout().addWidget(QPushButton('take screenshot', clicked=shoot))

widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 7):

Since Qt5, `grabWindow` and `grabWidget` are obsolete (see [Obsolete Members for QPixmap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap-obsolete.html))

Instead, you can use `QWidget.grab()`

```
p=widget.grab()
```

Comment: That's don't work in case you have a scroll area inside the MainWindow. It only prints the top part of window.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, instead of

```
p = QPixmap.grabWindow(widget.winId())
```

you can also use

```
p = QPixmap.grabWidget(widget)
```

Answer (score 0):

**PyQt5** update

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QScreen
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now()
filename = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.jpg')
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QScreen.grabWindow(app.primaryScreen(), 
QApplication.desktop().winId()).save(filename, 'png')
```

Comment: This is saving the whole screen and not a single window.

Comment: It's the update for PyQt5, replace desktop with a widget you want to grab as pointed in the answers above.